# ReactiveX: filter out numbers from observable so that total never goes below zero

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex

The following RxJs code displays numbers from the input list and the running total:

```
let inputs = [10, 10, -30, 10, -30, 50, -25, -30, 10]

let obs$ = Rx.Observable.from(inputs)
let totals$ = obs$.scan((acc, next) => acc + next, 0)
obs$.subscribe(x => console.log('x:', x));
totals$.subscribe(x => console.log("total:", x))
```

`totals$` will emit: 10, 20, -10, 0, -30...

I would like to transform the `obs$` observable somehow, so that the resulting `totals$` never emits a negative number.

I.e., in this case, both first and last "-30" should be filtered out:

`otherObs$`: 10, 10, 10, -30, 50, -25, 10

`totals$`: 10, 20, 30, 0, 50, 25, 35

edit: Note that I'm interested in the modified `otherObs$` observable, i.e., a sequence of the original input numbers with some filtered out (`obs$` will actually contain more data, so I really do need the original elements; the "value" is just a key to filter on). The `totals$` here is *only* for showing what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @CozyAzure's ideas, I figured out a better answer. I simply need to store more state in the reducer: the original value, the accumulated total, and whether this value was added to the total or not.

```
let other$ = obs$
  .scan(({value, total, valid}, next) => {
     if (total + next < 0)
       return { value: next, total: total, valid: false }
     else
       return { value: next, total: total + next, valid: true }
  }, { value: undefined, total: 0, valid: false })
  .filter(x => x.valid)
  .map(x => x.value)
```

This way, I can filter out the values that were *not* added, and get back the original values that were.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that by incorporating that logic in your reduce function, aka inside the `.scan()`:

```
let total$ = obs$.scan((acc, next) => {
    if (acc + next < 0) { //less than zero, don't take in the current number
        return acc;
    }
    return acc + next; //all is good, continue to add next
}, 0)
```

Or even in one liner:

```
let totals$ = obs$.scan((acc, next) => (acc + next < 0 ? acc : acc + next), 0)
```

If you want to retain each and every value and still check the sum, then there is no choice but to store each sequence in the array:

```
let other$ =
    obs$
        .scan((acc, next) => {
            let sum = acc.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
            if((sum+next)<0){
                return acc; // less than zero, return current arrray
            }
            return  acc.push(next); //greater or equal to zero, add current item to array
        }, [...0])
        .switchMap(array => Observable.from(array))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm interested in numbers from the original sequence, not in the total. I want to get an observable, such that when I apply my original `totals$` reduce, I get the non-negatives